# Custom row and columns selection pandas

Tags: pandas

I wish to select custom rows and custom columns from pandas.

I located the indices of my desired rows and they are.

```
indices_rows = [224, 290, 390, 130, 262, 338]
```

and index of the first column and index of the last column I wish to have in my DataFrame.

`index_first = 26`, `index_last = 56229`

when I wish to extract the desired DataDrame with

```
new_df = data_raw.iloc[[indices_rows],index:index_last]
```

I get an error: `ValueError: Buffer has the wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)`

I have no idea why. Since separately they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[]` around `indices_rows`:

```
new_df = data_raw.iloc[indices_rows,index:index_last]
```

---

because:

```
new_df = data_raw.iloc[[indices_rows],index:index_last]
```

is:

```
new_df = data_raw.iloc[[[224, 290, 390, 130, 262, 338]],index:index_last]
```

And need:

```
new_df = data_raw.iloc[[224, 290, 390, 130, 262, 338],index:index_last]
```